# Invoke Django Signal only if the record is newly created - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I am using Django `post_save` signal, which will trigger whenever the new record is created. This signal is called every time a save action takes place. Even though it has the `created` boolean field, this function is executed all the time.

The problem here is, at each request I am updating the `User` table `last_login` and `last_active` fields. Hence on each request this signal is getting executed. even though we are having created Boolean field, the function call is happened. which may cause performance impact when we have million request at a time.

I am looking for a solution, the signal should get executed only if the new record is created in the `User` table.

Sample code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="call_method")
def call_method(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print ('>>>>>>>>>> Signal Called ', instance)
    if created:
        print ('$$$$$$$$$$$ User created')
```

Kindly help me to find the better solution.

Comment: Can you share the type of instructions that you want to execute inside the signal? There might be an opening for a quick and elegant solution there

Answer (score 0):

If you call save on an instance model there is really no way around not hooking into the signal.
However if you were to change the way you update your user instance you could skip the signal.

This for instance won't trigger the post_save event

```py
User.objects.filter(id=1).update(last_login=timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the logic implemented by your signal into custom_save() of your User class or rewrite the default save() function...

The trick is to place your instructions behind the condition that a primary key exists on the object being saved.
So, when the custom_save() or save() method is called, your logic behind it will only be executed on the first record (i.e. the creation)

Practical example:

```
class User(models.Model)
    ...
    email = models.Charfield(max_lenght=250, unique=True)

    # Overwrite Save method
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

        if not self.pk:   # Means that it is the first record of this object
            print (f'{self.email} User created')

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre_save signal for this.

pre_save:- To execute some code dealing with another part of your application before the object gets saved to the database, you have to use a pre_save signal.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="call_method")
def trigger_emails_to_employees(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk:  # A newly created object (not denotes that the instance does not exists till now)
        print("Send email, trigger msgs, block previous records")
        print("Do whatever you want before creating the new object")
    ------------------------------
    if instance.pk:  # Invokes only when object is being edited.
        print("Trigger editing object things before the object get updated")
        print("Do whatever you want before editing the existing object")
```